# Yii Query DB when `where` sometimes can be all (*) (omit one or more where clauses when necessary)

Tags: database, where-clause

Yii Query with multiple where conditions when one or more where conditions can sometimes be "get all", as in *

I tried omitting the relevant status clause entirely like so, but that obviously broke the code.

```
$orders = Orders::find()
 ->where(['currency' => $filterCurrency])
if ($filterStatus !== null){
 ->where(['status' => $filterStatus])    
}
->all();
```

Current code:

```
$filterCurrency = 'eur';
$filterStatus = null; // but can e.g. be 'Draft'

$orders = Orders::find()
 ->where(['currency' => $filterCurrency, 'status' => $filterStatus])
 ->all();
```

I'm looking for a result where if e.g. `$filterStatus` has a value of `*`, then ideally it won't be included in the query at all, thus not making the status column part of the query at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. The key is to break it into a query and use `andWhere` only if necessary.

```
$filterCurrency = 'eur';
$filterStatus = null; // but can e.g. be 'Draft'

$ordersQuery = Orders::find()
  ->where(['currency' => $filterCurrency]);

if ($filterStatus != '*') {
  $ordersQuery->andWhere(['status' => $filterStatus]);
}

$orders = $ordersQuery->all();
```